# Excel - Get Data from cells from all sheets, if text match

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a workbook where I have one sheet for each day there is in the current month. Example I have the following sheets for June:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
```

I then have another sheet called `Master`.

In each of the sheets, I have in cell `A1` the week number for the specific day. Example in sheets `13` to `19`, `A1` contains 24 (since it is week 24 in those dates).

In `Master`, `A1` is the week number of the sheets I should be getting data from. So here I can enter example 24 (it should then take specific data from all sheets, where `A1` = 24). **Is this possible?**

Specifically, I want to take the data from column `G3` and below, from every sheets where `A1` is 24, and copy the text to the `Master` sheet, column `B11` and down.

Comment: My first thought is that you could do that with the `Indirect()` formula, in combination with Index/Match. You would need a table somewhere that matches the week numbers to the days, and then use Indirect to address the sheet with the matched day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opnion it will be the easiest to loop through every single worksheet (except for the "Master" sheet), check if the weeknumber is the same as the weeknumber in the mastersheet and then perform any copy/past activities.

Example:

```
Sub Macro()

Dim masterws, ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim curweek As String

Set masterws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
curweek = masterws.Range("A1")

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

    If ws.Name <> "Master" Then

        If ws.Range("A1").Value = curweek Then
            'Perform your copy/past activities

        End If

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For your reference.
Use `indirect` function
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could use the following

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim weekN As Long, rowTopasteFrom As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsMst As Worksheet

    Set wsMst = Worksheets("Master")
    weekN = wsMst.Range("A1")

    If weekN <= 0 And weekN >= 53 Then Exit Sub '<--| exit if week is not a valid number

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Range("A1") = weekN Then '<--| first check if valid week number
            If ws.Name <> "Master" Then 
                With GetRange(ws, ws.Range("G3")) '<--| get the current worksheet range to copy values from
                    GetCellToPasteFrom(wsMst, 2, 11).Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value '<--| paste values in "Master"
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub

Function GetRange(ws As Worksheet, iniRng As Range) As Range
    With ws
        Set GetRange = .Range(iniRng, .Cells(.Rows.Count, iniRng.Column).End(xlUp))
    End With
End Function

Function GetCellToPasteFrom(ws As Worksheet, col As Long, Optional minRow As Variant) As Range
    Set GetCellToPasteFrom = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    If Not IsMissing(minRow) Then If GetCellToPasteFrom.Row < minRow Then Set GetCellToPasteFrom = ws.Cells(minRow, col)
End Function
```

as a side note, I put valid week number check before valid worksheet name one to have less of these latter checks (i.e. only for worksheets with proper week number)

not something to actually worry about in this particular case, but could be useful to think it over for more challenging environments